# JCombobox1 and json data convert static variable

Tags: java, json, swing, variables, gson

İ would like to add data jcombobox1 from json data.But İt's give two error;

**non-static variable JCombobox1 cannot be referanced from a static context error**

**non-static method getName()cannot be referanced from a static context error**

How could i convert static variable combobox and json variable

My java files;

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24618080/

```
private static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    int read;
    char[] chars = new char[1024];
    while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
        buffer.append(chars, 0, read); 

    return buffer.toString();
   } finally {
    if (reader != null)
        reader.close();
   }
    }
public static class MySQLEntry {
public String id;
public static String ad;
public String latitude;
public String longitude;
public String speed;
public String hour;
public String day;
public String adres;
public String resimyol;

 public String getId() { return id; }
public String getName() { return ad;  }
public String getlat() { return latitude; }
public String getlon() { return longitude; }
 public String getspeed() { return speed; }
 public String gethour() { return hour; }
 public String getday() { return day; }
 public String getadres() { return adres; }
public String getresim() { return resimyol; }

     }

   public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new KonumGoster().setVisible(true);

             String json = null;
            try {
                json = readUrl("http://url.esy.es/"
                        + "json.php");
            } catch (Exception ex) {

Logger.getLogger(KonumGoster.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

 Gson gson = new Gson();     

   MySQLEntry[] array = gson.fromJson(json, MySQLEntry[].class);
   JComboBox jComboBox1 = new JComboBox(array);
for (MySQLEntry obj : array) {
 //MySQLEntry x =new MySQLEntry(obj.getName());


jComboBox1.addItem(obj.getName());

System.out.println("ID: " +obj.getId());
System.out.println("Ad: " +obj.getName());
System.out.println("Latitude: " +obj.getlat());
System.out.println("Longitude: " +obj.getlon());
System.out.println("Speed: " +obj.getspeed());
System.out.println("Saat: " +obj.gethour());
System.out.println("Tarih: " +obj.getday());
System.out.println("Açık Adres: " +obj.getadres());
System.out.println("Harita Üzerinde: " +obj.getresim());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error 1 : *non-static variable JCombobox1 cannot be referanced from a static context error*

Thats mean **JComboBox** is non static but your **MySQLEntry** is static that why JComboBox cannot be populate with static class or method.

Change your class like this:

```
public final class MySQLEntry
```

Error 2: *non-static method getName()cannot be referanced from a static context error*

It's same error with first...

Your name getter is non static but the variable is static and you need to make both static or both non-static like :

```
private static String ad;
public static String getAd(){return this.ad;}
```

OR

```
private String ad;
public String getAd(){return this.ad;}
```